# Simple ClickOnce Deployment from Webpage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, clickonce, web-deployment

I am new to ClickOnce deployment and unfortunately got stuck quite early. Upfront, I am not a programmer in the first place..

The task would be to run an application written in Visual/C# from a website. In the end, my problem is how to get my compiled project linked to a website so someone can execute it from there. Where must which files be located/ whats the important code.
See, I dont have much knowledge in web-development..

What would be the most simple set-up to understand the concept?

I would also highly appreaciate any recommendations for tutorials, etc.

Regards,
mulm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually "run a C# program from a website" but you can download it to a users machine and execute it from there. Either Clickonce or XBAP (depending on the architecture of the client application you are attempting to run) is the way to do this. Clearly they will only run on Windows client PCs though.

Visual Studio does have a lot of tools that make publishing ClickOnce applications vrey straightforward, so I'd follow the microsoft tutorials on publishing them (there is literally a button in Visual Studio that says "publish" for deploying ClickOnce applications to a web location).

If you look inside the published .Html you can see its just a URL to a .application file. Open the .application file and its just an XML file listing the application components to install, strong names, and dependencies. The .application extension is recognised by Windows IE which interrogates it and downloads and installs the nominated files. It installs the files into a user-local and app version specific location (the user cannot choose where to install it) and adds a link to the desktop. When the user launches it, a wrapper application checks the original URL location for an updated .application and installs the new copy if there is one, otherwise it launches the existing one.

One thing that often causes problems for ClickOnce users is that there is no built-in way to determine which site your ClickOnce application was launched or installed from - and typically the application author wants to interact with a data source available on that site. You will need to modify the .application file by hand to add in that kind of data, and re-sign it (it has a checksum built in) before making it available. This process is covered here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465299.aspx  which also has a  lot of background on the process.

Comment: You are right of course, I wasnt precise; what I meant by "run from website" was the "available online only" option. My problem is that most explanations go through the publish wizard and then stop with creation of the publish.htm